# Uploading and resizing images with Firebase, Expo React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, expo

**What is the recommended Image upload and resize approach with the below Tech Stack** :

1. Firebase (Cloud Firestore, Cloud functions, Realtime Database, Cloud storage)
2. Expo React Native

I am wondering if anyone has insight on this in regards to performance, efficiency etc.

**Here’s what we’ve tried**

1. Upload Image function with this (https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2402#issuecomment-443726662) + Expo Image Manipulator. All this on the front end
2. fetch apiUrl endpoint with formData + busboy https onRequest with with ImageMagick resizer (backend)
3. Allowing user to upload image of any size + onFinalize() backend cloud function with ImageMagick resize and then update path of image and finally delete old image later ?

Which is highly recommended ? Are there alternatives ? Please me know.

Answer (score 1):

The first recommendation I'd make is to not consider any of the products you mention for storing images, but instead use Cloud Storage (for which a Firebase SDK is also available).

The simplest way to then resize the image after it's been uploaded is through the [Resize Images](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images) extension that Firebase providers. The extension is just a pre-built set of Cloud Functions, so if you want different behavior you can always fork its code and roll your own based on that.